# Is it possible to send an ICMP echo request from a swf?

Tags: actionscript, icmp, traceroute

ActionScript 3 can send UDP packets via [flash.net.DatagramSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html). Is their any way to send an ICMP packet? I'd also like to set the TTL flag so I can implement [traceroute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) in an SWF.

Answer (score 3):

UDP is not available on Flash Player, only on Adobe AIR runtime. So if you are not targeting a browser, you can use it. I don't know if you can send an ICMP packet with DatagramSocket - but you could try to set the TTL like this example: http://blog.debit.nl/2010/06/mdns-daap-announce-air-2-0/

And you might be interested to see the flash.net.dns package: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/dns/package-detail.html