# How do I set the TTL of a UDP packet in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, udp, traceroute

I want to make [traceroute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) in the browser via flash. [I asked about ICMP packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598296/is-it-possible-to-send-an-icmp-echo-request-from-a-swf), but another alternative would be UDP packets if I could set the TTL. However, I don't see that option in [flash.net.DatagramSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use UDP in a web browser via flash. the Datagram socket is only accessible when running in the AIR player.

Your best option is a signed java applet.

Comment: That or possibly Silverlight I guess.